# php: 2 mysql queries but only 1 is executed

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a class in php that needs to send data from a form to a database. The query is split up in 2 queries bcs half the data needs to be send to an other table in the same database.

Now the problem: When I confirm the form then only the data of the sec query have been send to the database but not the data of the first query.

this is what I have:

(database connection) ...

```
if (something is empty)
{
 Give error.
}
else {

$query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO Table1(coloumn1, coloumn2, coloumn3, coloumn4, coloumn5, coloumn6, coloumn7, coloumn8) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    $query->bindParam(1, $Val1);
    $query->bindParam(2, $Val2);
    $query->bindParam(3, $Val3);
    $query->bindParam(4, $Val4);
    $query->bindParam(5, $Val5);
    $query->bindParam(6, $Val6);
    $query->bindParam(7, $Val7);
    $query->bindParam(8, $Val8);

    $query->execute();

    $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO Table2(coloumn1, coloumn2, coloumn3, coloumn4, coloumn5) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    $query->bindParam(1, $Val1);
    $query->bindParam(2, $Val9);
    $query->bindParam(3, $Val10);
    $query->bindParam(4, $Val11);
    $query->bindParam(5, $Val12);

    $query->execute();
  }
```

What I have done:

- checked database connection
- checked table name
- some error checks
- trying to make a different function for the sec query (but then he
  doesn't send anything anymore)
- delete the sec query (but it still wont send the first query)
- and ofc googling

I think i am doing something wrong with my first query but I don't know what.

---

Found it misspelled a column name (yes i did check it 2 times but still didn't saw it).

Comment: Do your `$query->execute();` calls return true? if not you should try to get the error message. for example with adding this after your db connection: `$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );`

Comment: I really hope your column names aren't actually named like that

Comment: I would bet this isn't your real code. Hopefully, given your column naming style, it isn't the actual version. So we can't be sure if you've introduced or removed an error when you've made this example. Post the real code - we can't fix what we can't see. And as others have said, check the return value from the execute command, and make sure error reporting is enabled. Also, if both these queries need to run successfully for the data to make sense, wrap them in a transaction and do a rollback if either one fails.

Comment: Found it... I updated the  question. Thanks Roland Starke found it with the setAtrribute.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you used the bind_param method in the wrong way. As stated in http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php:

```
bool mysqli_stmt::bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )
```

So, assuming all your variables are integers, you could bind them in the following way:

```
$query->bind_param('iiiiiiii', $Val1, $Val2, $Val3, $Val4, $Val5, $Val6, $Val7, $Val8);
```

Here are the type specification chars:

- 'i': corresponding variable has type integer
- 'd': corresponding variable has type double
- 's': corresponding variable has type string
- 'b': corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets

Therefore the solution I propose you is:

```
$query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO Table1(coloumn1, coloumn2, coloumn3, coloumn4, coloumn5, coloumn6, coloumn7, coloumn8) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$query->bind_param('iiiiiiii', $Val1, $Val2, $Val3, $Val4, $Val5, $Val6, $Val7, $Val8);

$query->execute();

$query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO Table2(coloumn1, coloumn2, coloumn3, coloumn4, coloumn5) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$query->bind_param('iiiii', $Val1, $Val9, $Val10, $Val11, $Val12);

$query->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

`bind_param` isn't supposed to be used the way you were using it for mysqli:

[mysqli_stmt_bind_param documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

The first parameters is a hint to PHP about what type of variable you are dealing  with (`i`=>integer, `s`=> string, etc.)

You basically have to give ALL parameters in one line, using VARIABLES (you can't use constants).

--- SIDE NOTE: ADVANCED ---

If your code doesn't know how many parameters to pass at compile time, you might need to use:

```
call_user_func_array(array($query,'bind_param'), $all_prm );
```

where `$all_prm` is a an array of references to the values, first element being the types.